# Sending JavaScript code to a Web Surveillance Server (CCTV) in Android

Tags: javascript, android, json

Im trying to send the pan tilt zoom commands to a web surveillance server provided by the device (DVR). I am able to access everything in the web server and i used fire bug in firefox to locate the specific JavaScript command that the buttons are sending to the server. I want to send that specific line of code from my android app. Should I use JSON or SOAP? Im not familiar with these two but i think it is the way to do it, i just don't know what to do specifically with these concepts.

---

this is the sample JavaScript i got from the web surveillance using firebug:

**This is the content of the anchor tag:**

```
<a class="y4" onmouseout="ajaxFunction('stop','directionleft')"
onmouseup="ajaxFunction('stop','directionleft')" 
onmousedown="ajaxFunction('start','directionleft')" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

---

**This is the script of the "ajaxFunction":**

```
function ajaxFunction(req, param)
{
var xmlHttp;
try
{
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e)
{
    try
    {
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert("ÄúµÄä¯ÀÀÆ÷²»Ö§³ÖAJAX£¡");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

if(g_viewStatu[g_clicked].vbPlaying)
{
    if(req=="start")
    {
    xmlHttp.open("POST","dvrcmd",true);
    xmlHttp.send("command=ptz_req&req="+req+"&param="+param+"&channel="+g_viewStatu[g_clicked].nchannel+"&stream="+g_channelStatu[g_viewStatu[g_clicked].nchannel].streamStyle);
    ptzstate = 1;
    }

    else if(req=="stop" && ptzstate == 1)
    {
    xmlHttp.open("POST","dvrcmd",true);
    xmlHttp.send("command=ptz_req&req="+req+"&param="+param+"&channel="+g_viewStatu[g_clicked].nchannel+"&stream="+g_channelStatu[g_viewStatu[g_clicked].nchannel].streamStyle);
    ptzstate = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I know there are a lot this kind of apps in Playstore, but this one is for our Thesis.

Comment: You have, right here in your question, the exact payload HTTP request you want to send.  What are you asking?

Comment: @SLaks how to acctually send them using android because most of the threads that i've been reading, they have different parameters like ("username", "theusername") <-- this is what are they actually requesting, but mine is different because i have the actual script to send.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  You aren't sending a "script"; you're sending a string body in an HTTP request.  Do you understand exactly what that Javascript does? Did you watch it in action in the browser dev tools?

Comment: @SLaks so if i just send this from android as a string in an HTTP request, will it actually do what this command says? 

im pertaining to this line of code ---> 

xmlHttp.open("POST","dvrcmd",true);    xmlHttp.send("command=ptz_req&req="+req+"&param="+param+"&channel="+g_viewStatu[g_clicked].nchannel+"&stream="+g_channelStatu[g_viewStatu[g_clicked].nchannel].streamStyle);

Comment: Yes.  As long as you send the same POST body, the server has no idea what the request is coming from.  You may need to set matching HTTP headers too.

Comment: @SLaks thanks i'll try to find out more about this "http headers" and such, im not that good im sorry. i'll just mention you here if i have more questions if it will be fine with you

Comment: hey @SLaks you online? how can i send this whole string body alone? and what about headers? im sorry these things are new to me.

Comment: The string you want is `"command=ptz_req&req="+req+"&param="+param+"&channel="+g_viewStatu[‌​g_clicked].nchannel+"&stream="+g_channelStatu[g_viewStatu[g_clicked].nchannel].st‌​reamStyle`.  You can see the headers that the browser sends in the network tab in your dev tools.  They may not be necessary.  Also, look at Fiddler, which will let you try this.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to learn HTTP.

Comment: ok thanks for that.. i really need to learn about this. @SLaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question.. >.<

```
public void executePTZ(String cmd, String direction){

    String posturl = "http://192.168.1.120";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(posturl);


    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("command=ptz_req&req="+cmd+"&param="+direction+"&channel=1&stream=1"));
        HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```